# How do I package properly with JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, maven, jruby

I'm coding a project that uses JRuby and I want to be able to do three things in one command, right off the bat after cloning the repository.

1. Install rubygem dependencies.
2. Install maven dependencies.
3. Package everything into a standalone jar, including JRuby.

What is the simplest and most straightforward way to achieve this? I could probably hack around with custom build commands in my pom.xml, but it seems like other people must have wanted to do this before. I don't want to mess around with a shell script that downloads stuff through maven and then shoves my ruby code into ruby-complete.jar, after "java -jar ruby-complete.jar -S gem install"ing my gems. I want a simple, declarative file that says: "these are the dependencies, now parse me and figure out how to get what cheshircat wants."

Is there a way to do this with maven? I've tried jbundler, but it keeps giving me errors, and I've tried it on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the torquebox jruby-maven-plugins.  I use them for my work to do two of the three requirements you list:

1. 'Install rubygem dependencies' using the gem-maven-plugin
2. 'Install maven plugins' like any other plugin because it's maven and maven is driving the build and packaging.

The gems get installed to your project's ./target/rubygems directory.

I am sure you can jar up whatever you want with the maven-jar-plugin.

I wrote up a more detailed explanation:

http://thechurchofautomation.com/java-ruby-interoperability-torquebox-maven-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the maven dependencies, but in general warbler is the tool you want for packaging up everything, including jruby and gem dependencies, into a standalone jar.

https://github.com/jruby/warbler

It will do .war as well as .jar.  If your thing doesn't look like a webapp (doesn't have a rack.up file), it'll do a jar though, just what you want.

It doesn't need any extra declarative config, it just uses what you've already got, like your Gemfile.

You may have to do maven as an extra step, but you could try asking the warbler folks for advice.

Comment: How do I contact the warbler folks?

Comment: you DO not ... their busy as they are - try to read the README/wiki :) !